# Batch File 1 time-pad encryption

Tags: batch-file, encryption

I'm currently trying to code an encryption batch file that is unbreakable.

How it works(I think):

if you type the letter "a" the encryption file would change the output to whatever encryption key it had.

So "a"="e"
but next time you type it
"a"=="f"
and text time you type a
"a"=="b"

The one problem is I don't know how to make it random. %random% won't work because it's just numbers. The batch file would have to detect every time you type a certain letter then set a %random% and every possible %random% would equal a different number or letter or symbol.

```
set /p string==:
%random%=q
%random%=w
%random%=e
%random%=r
%random%=t
%random%=y
%random%=u
%random%=i
%random%=o
%random%=p
%random%=a
%random%=s
%random%=d
%random%=f
%random%=g
%random%=h
%random%=j
%random%=k
%random%=l
%random%=z
%random%=x
%random%=c
%random%=v
%random%=b
%random%=n
%random%=m
```

I'm not sure how to decode something like that either.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I guess there is some misunderstanding on how OTP-encryption works. You need to generate the random OTP **before** encrypting something (and transfer the OTP on a secure channel, ideally by exchanging a physical data storage). It is crucial, that the OTP is truly random-generated (batch will only generate pseudo random numbers) and that only sender and receiver have access to the contents of the OTP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your strategy.

Suppose you encrypt "bookkeeper" for instance to "lwpr39amkx" - now how are you going to decrypt that string - given that the random number-sequence used to encrypt the string is unrepeatable, or even if you are aware precisely of the number-sequence used to encrypt it?